# How to check inline javascript before its execution?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to create a Firefox extension to check scripts before they are executed and possibly remove them.

However, i've got some problems with inline scripts. They are immediately executed once loaded, even if the whole document isn't.

Is there a way to "intercept" an inline script when it's loaded but before it's executed ?

Things i saw blocked every script, i only want to block specific scripts and keep the website working.

Comment: Check it for what?

Comment: For removal depending on what it does or is.

Comment: Short answer: no.
The farthest you could get is Mutation Observer on document loading, but it executes afterwards script execution, essentially serving zero purpose for you. What you're trying to do requires low level API and there's no such API yet.

Comment: Damn. :/ Strange nobody thought about that before. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but you can try different approach with delayed render (which is bad and sad). Your document body should contain only a single script that fetches all the remaining content and inserts it into body after all the transformations have been done. For the sake of simplicity I'm using jQuery here.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      $.ajax('link-to-remaining-data').done(function(data){
        // transform your data here and insert it into body
        $(transformedData).appendTo('body');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a big hack so I wouldn't use that on a production unless everything else in your app is client rendered.